# JavaScript Image Gallery 2

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, image-gallery

I don't know if this question has been asked before or not. But...

I have the following JavaScript code in my HTML file:

```
<img id="imageDisplay">

<script type="text/javascript">
   var displayImage = document.querySelector( '#imageDisplay' );

   var imageArray = [ 'http://www.joongcho.com/Images/30th-Bday-Party-01.jpg',
                      'http://www.joongcho.com/Images/30th-Bday-Party-02.jpg',
                      'http://www.joongcho.com/Images/30th-Bday-Party-03.jpg',
                      'http://www.joongcho.com/Images/30th-Bday-Party-04.jpg',
                      'http://www.joongcho.com/Images/30th-Bday-Party-05.jpg',
                      'http://www.joongcho.com/Images/30th-Bday-Party-06.jpg' ];
   var imageCount = 0;
   var imageLength = imageArray.length;

   displayImage.setAttribute( 'src', imageArray[ imageCount ] );

   function nextImage(imageCount) {
   }

   function previousImage(imageCount) {
   }
</script>
```

I'm trying to put a next Image and a previous Image function for this HTML.

For the next image, if there are more than 1 images and the image is not the last image, then there should be a link that allows a user to click through the array forwards. Also, if the image is the last image in the array, then the link is hidden.

For the previous image, if the image is not the first image of the array, then there should be a link that allows a user click through the array backwards. if the image is the first image, then the previous link should be hidden.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach event listeners to buttons or links (I used buttons):

```js
var displayImage = document.getElementById('imageDisplay');
var buttonPrev = document.getElementById('button-prev');
var buttonNext = document.getElementById('button-next');

var imageArray = [ '../Images/30th-Bday-Party-01.jpg',
                      '../Images/30th-Bday-Party-02.jpg',
                      '../Images/30th-Bday-Party-03.jpg',
                      '../Images/30th-Bday-Party-04.jpg',
                      '../Images/30th-Bday-Party-05.jpg',
                      '../Images/30th-Bday-Party-06.jpg' ];
var imageCount = 0;
var imageLength = imageArray.length;

function nextImage () {
  imageCount++;
  if (imageCount >= imageLength - 1) {
    buttonNext.style.display = 'none';
    imageCount = imageLength - 1;
  } 
  if (imageCount < imageLength) {
    displayImage.setAttribute('src', imageArray[imageCount]);
  }
  if (imageCount > 0) {
    buttonPrev.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}

function previousImage () {
  imageCount--;
  if (imageCount <= 0) {
    buttonPrev.style.display = 'none';
    imageCount = 0;
  } 
  if (imageCount >= 0) {
    displayImage.setAttribute('src', imageArray[imageCount]);
  }
  if (imageCount < imageLength) {
    buttonNext.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}

displayImage.setAttribute('src', imageArray[imageCount]);
displayImage.textContent = imageCount;
buttonPrev.style.display = 'none';
buttonNext.addEventListener('click', nextImage);
buttonPrev.addEventListener('click', previousImage);
```

```html
<img id="imageDisplay" />
<button id="button-prev">Back</button>
<button id="button-next">Forward</button>
```

Of course, you can't look at the images yet.

Comment: When I run this code on my end it works fine, but when you click the Previous button, the next button will disappear altogether, not giving the opportunity to go forward again. Also, you can't go to the first image on my end.

Also, can you add the following to the images section: 'http://www.joongcho.com/Images/' to see it working. Thank you.

Comment: This works now with a few tweaks, but it doesn't work on all browsers.

For e.g., it works fine in Google Chrome, but for some reason, it won't work properly in IE 11+. The next button works fine, but the previous button won't show up in Internet Explorer.

[link]http://www.joongcho.com/downloads/random-a.htm[/link] is the example.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right. Seems like IE doesn't support [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/initial). I edited my answer, now it should work.

Comment: In the example above, can I use a hyperlink as a button instead of using the button as navigation to display the next/previous images?